# Hebrew chars in email sent with JavaMail appears as question marks

Tags: email, internationalization, jakarta-mail, hebrew

What can be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you setting the character encoding correctly?

try this:

```
mimemessage.setText(s6,"utf-8");
```

you may need utf-16, cant remember what char set hebrew is on off the top of my head.

try here http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/codepages.html

Comment: UTf-8 and UTF-16 are encodings, not charsets. Both support all Unicode characters (and thus for all practical purposes, ALL characters)

Answer (score 0):

3 years late, but if someone hits this one, I found the answer:

```
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart("alternative");

        BodyPart htmlPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        htmlPart.setContent(new String(messageHtml.getBytes("UTF8"),"ISO-8859-1"), "text/html");
        multipart.addBodyPart(htmlPart);

        message.setContent(multipart);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
        message.setSubject(subject, "UTF-8");
```

The trick was to convert my html from UTF-8 (the way it came from my message_iw.properties), and then transform it into ISO format, so that there's no need to set any headers.

Comment: by the ISO-8859-1 I believe you are using LATIN language ? if so, please say that your answer relates to a specific language